# Is there a way to "flatten" a search across Stack Exchange sites without going to an external search engine (not that that's bad)?

Tags: support, search, asking-questions

Watching the [Vsauce](https://www.youtube.com/c/vsauce1/videos) short [The Only Element You Can Chew Like Gum](https://youtu.be/Xed60vrCuVM) I was intrigued by

> This is indium, the only element in the universe that is safe, and soft enough to chew like bubble gum... it softened as it warmed up in my mouth and I could tell it was metal *because I could feel the vibrations of the crystals **twinning***.

A question about the vibrations caused by dynamic [Crystal twinning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crystal_twinning) could be searched or asked under (for example, not necessarily exhaustive):

- [metallurgy](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/metallurgy) (163 questions) tag in Engineering SE
- [metallurgy](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/metallurgy) (179) and/or [crystallography](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/crystallography) (269) tags in Chemistry SE
- [crystals](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/crystals) (941) and/or [metals](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/metals) (507) tags in Physics SE
- [crystallography](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/crystallography) (112) and/or [grain-boundaries](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grain-boundaries) (4) in Matter Modeling SE
- [crystals](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/crystals) (32) and/or [crystallography](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/crystallography) (38) and/or [mineralogy](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mineralogy) (175) in Earth Science SE

Is there a way *within Stack Exchange* to flatten my searching for questions and answers about things related to phenomenon like crystallographic twinning in metals under deformation without going outside and using a search engine?

I am not saying that there's anything wrong with using a search engine! I'm just asking if there is also something internal and site-flattened.

Comment: There's a network-wide search on [Stack Exchange homepage](https://stackexchange.com/), if that's what you're looking for.

Comment: @MetaAndrewT. that seems to be the answer! I'm a long-time active user but have never really gone to the home page, so had never seen the search feature there. Perhaps that's true for some others as well, so I think a short and accepted answer post would be great! (cf. https://stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bcrystallography%5D+twinning)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a search on the [Stack Exchange homepage](https://stackexchange.com/).  This will search all the sites.